# Is there virtual webcam software that accepts a HTTP stream as a video source?

Tags: windows, webcam, video-streaming, virtual-webcam

I need to stream video from DVBViewer's Netstreamer plugin, and capturing its onscreen video output is too laggy.

Is there any virtual webcam software that accepts HTTP Live Streams as a video source?

Comment: which operating system?

Answer (score 0):

If you are on linux you could just use [v4l2loopback with mplayer](https://github.com/umlaeute/v4l2loopback/wiki/Mplayer).

1. Download it,
2. compile it (`make` and `su -c 'make install'`),
3. load the module with `su -c 'modprobe v4l2loopback'`,
4. then change one line in the file `examples/yuv4mpeg_to_v4l2.c` of the v4l2loopback source folder from

   ```
   v.fmt.pix.pixelformat = V4L2_PIX_FMT_YUV420;
   ```

   to

   ```
   v.fmt.pix.pixelformat = V4L2_PIX_FMT_YVU420;
   ```
5. and do `make` in this folder.
6. Then run it from the `examples` directory like this:

   ```
   mkfifo /tmp/pipe  # only needed once, as long as you do not delete the file /tmp/pipe
   ./yuv4mpeg_to_v4l2 < /tmp/pipe &
   mplayer movie.mp4 -vf scale=480:360 -vo yuv4mpeg:file=/tmp/pipe
   ```

   where you replace `movie.mp4` with the name of your video file. And replace `/dev/video0` with your loopback device.

MPlayer is able to play any webstreams, all kind of video files and so on. I just tested it with a file from http://www.tagesschau.de which is a german news site.

```
TS=$(wget "http://www.tagesschau.de/multimedia/video/" -q -O - | grep --regexp='http.*\.webm"' | sed -e 's%.*href="%%' -e 's%\.webm".*%\.webm%')
./yuv4mpeg_to_v4l2 < /tmp/pipe &
mplayer $TS -vf scale=480:360 -vo yuv4mpeg:file=/tmp/pipe
```